# How do you override the Icon for iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, icons

I remember reading somewhere that you can provide your own icons without having them pass them through the automatic gloss effect when compiling an iphone app, but I can't remember how to do it, and not sure where it was in the docs. Anyone here remembers?

thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon (actually the linked version came later, but I think it has the better answer with the screen cap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the "UIPrerenderedIcon" to your info.plist file, change it to be a boolean and make it true. (In 2.0 of the iPhone OS you could also leave it as a string and use YES or NO, but that no longer works in 2.1.)

Answer (score 4):

Stephen is correct. The exact syntax that works in 2.1 is:

```
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing that down as its an intuitive way to describe a boolean