# How to disable highlighting of the app icon?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I disable the highlighting that appears on my icon while it's being displayed on the home page of iPhone?

Thanks.

Comment: XCode4: "highlighting" == "gloss effect"

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The easiest way is to check the Prerendered check box on your target's Summary tab:

[image: Prerendered Icon]

Alternatively, set the value of `Icon files (iOS 5) > Primary Icon > Icon already includes gloss effects` to `YES` in your application's Info.plist.

[image: Icon already includes gloss effects]

Comment: This definitely works, but the iPhone simulator sometimes holds onto the 'glossy' version. In this case, removing the app from the simulator and deleting the build directory seems to force the icon to refresh

Comment: Just to let eveyone know the property list key is now called:Icon already includes gloss effects. I am using xCode 3.2.6 with IOS 4.3

Comment: Just because this is a popular question, This have been updated in newer versions of the SDK, you should now look for `Icon already includes gloss and bevel effects` and Check that key. Hope this helps new people.

Comment: For iOS5 devices there's a new key structure, rather than a single on/off key, there's a CFBundleIcons dictionary, containing a CFBundlePrimaryIcon dictionary which contains an array of CFBundleIconFiles.  The BOOL UIPrerenderedIcon key goes in the CFBundlePrimaryIcon dictionary.

Comment: XCode 4: Go to `Project Target > Summary > App Icon` and check the checkbox `Prerendered` which disables the gloss effect. Note that in the Simulator sometimes the effect is not applied after clean & rebuild. If so, delete the build folder from the simulator as well.

Comment: @Will, I have a question about this. Setting this checkbox works for me. However, I don't see the icons in the boxes next to the checkbox. I added them directly to the plist file. How do I get them to appear in those boxes?

Comment: How to do this in XCode5/iOS7? I know the gloss effect doesn't exist anymore in iOS7. But how do you configure it for iOS6 compatibility?

Comment: See @Tiago's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19391351/414037) for Xcode 5 solution

Comment: Regarding XCode5/iOS7: In case you do not use xcassets, just combine @Will Haris and @Naveed Rafi answers and set the `Icon already includes gloss effects` to `YES` in both places.

Answer (score 32):

In new xcode 4 all you need is to add a new entry and search the following in list:

"Icon already includes gloss effects"

Example:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

I tried this several times and became slightly frustrated because it wasn't working. Turns out I already had this option set to NO and hidden under Icon files.

[image]

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Yeah - this seems to be new for iOS 5. There are now two different entries for the icons, and two for the "Icon already includes gloss effect"aka UIPrerenderedIcon property. Both need to be set.

Answer (score 18):

In Xcode 5 this setting changed place. In order to access it select your `xcassets`, select the app icon entry and, in the attributes inspector, select the `iOS icon is pre-rendered` checkbox.

[image: Turn on pre-rendered icon in Xcode 5]

Comment: Any way we can change this to the correct answer? The earlier one, while correct, is by and large irrelevant almost five years later.

Answer (score 13):

From the iPhone HIG:

> Note: If you choose, you can prevent iPhone OS from adding the shine to your icon. To do this, you need to add the UIPrerenderedIcon key to your application’s Info.plist file (read iPhone Application Programming Guide to learn about this file).
>   Your icon should still measure 57 x 57 pixels, regardless of whether you take advantage of the added shine.

Answer (score 7):

Open your `Info.plist` file, can also be named `ProjectName-Info.plist`, and add a new line. The *Key*-column is a drop down list, click it and scroll through a quite large set of keys in human readable form that are possible to set.

The one you are looking for is called *"Icon already includes gloss and bevel effects"*, that is the human readable form. Writing `UIPrerenderedIcon`, also works.

Adding this flag will also disable the automatic addition of gloss and bevel in Tunes Store, and on the App Store.

Answer (score 6):

[UIPrerenderedIcon](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-SW16) is the setting that you want to set.

Actually, it is probably a good idea to read through all of the Info.plist options you can set. It may save you from trying to replicate some functionality that is provided by default.

Answer (score 6):

The "Friendly" version of this key is now displayed by XCode 4 as "Icon already includes gloss effects" in case anyone else has trouble finding it.

Answer (score 5):

Set `UIPrerenderedIcon` to true in your `Info.plist`.

Comment: (This answer was merged from a duplicate question)

Answer (score 5):

From Xcode 4.3 there is a checkbox called "Prerendered" next to the icon in the Target/Summary configuration. Check that and the shine will be not added. For me "Icon already includes gloss effects" did not work.

[image: Check "Prerendered to remove shine effect"]

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 4.3.2, you can also use the Key `Icon already includes gloss effects` and set it's value to `YES`. This removed the glossy shine for me from my app icon.