# How to remove the "white reflection" on the application icon?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon)

Hi this is an iPhone objective C question.

When I set the icon file for the app, say, icon.png. When it is shown on the phone, a white reflection effect is automatically added on the icon.png

Is there any way to remove te reflection effect? Cause I can see that there are apps without the white reflection effect on the icons

Comment: oh thx a lot. sorry about the duplicate... i'm unable to search that question out before, haven't thought about the word 'highlighting'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Open your `Info.plist` file, can also be named `ProjectName-Info.plist`, and add a new line. The Key-column is a drop down list, click it and scroll through a quite large set of keys in human readable form that are possible to set.

The one you are looking for is called *"Icon already includes gloss and bevel effects"*, that is the human readable form. Writing `UIPrerenderedIcon`, also works.

Adding this flag will also disable the automatic addition of gloss and bevel in Tunes Store, and on the App Store.

Comment: Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453680/how-to-remove-the-white-reflection-on-the-application-icon

Answer (score 13):

In Xcode 4.3.2 you might also need to define the icons as pre-rendered.

Click on your project on the left, select your target, and under the Summary tab you'll see the App Icons, along with a "Prerendered"checkbox. Check this box and rerun your app.

If the icon hasnt changed yet, you might also need to delete and reinstall (rerun) the app on your device, or perhaps even restart the device, before the new icon is used.

[image: App Icon image]

Comment: The restarting of your device did solve the issue of not seeing changes. This is a key bit IMO :)

Answer (score 9):

In your info.plist file, add a key called `UIPrerenderedIcon` and set its value to true.

This will prevent the sdk from automatically adding the glossy shine to your icon