# When creating an iOS app (Xcode), how can I turn off the automatic icon 'gelling'

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, icons

Is there a way to get rid of the highlight that is automatically added to the icon when creating an iphone app, or will I have to compensate by hand in PS?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon)

Answer (score 9):

Set `UIPrerenderedIcon` to `YES` in your Info.plist.

For more information see: [Information Property List Key Reference: UIKit Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW16)

Comment: Thank you, I was looking in the .plist file but couldn't find the key (just found out you can 'view raw values').

Answer (score 1):

You can find it listed as "Icon already includes gloss effects" if you don't want to see the raw values.