# after submiting the project to app store ,why appstore image(512*512) geting glass effect?

Tags: iphone, icons, store

After submitting the project to app store, why is the App Store image(512*512) shown with a glass effect?

My original image does not have a glass effect, but after uploading, it is getting a glass effect. How can I avoid this glass effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon)

Answer (score 1):

That is done by default, just like it's done to your app icon.  Take a look at this

[When creating an iOS app (Xcode), how can I turn off the automatic icon 'gelling'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908405/when-creating-an-ios-app-xcode-how-can-i-turn-off-the-automatic-icon-gelling)