# How do I configure my application icon so that it doesn't appear as a standard iPhone button?

Tags: iphone, configuration, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon)

Hi all.

In each of my apps, the icon on the iPhone screen gets automatically converted into one of Apple's shiny buttons.  I am noticing that some apps have managed to either (a) turned off the shiny appearance (such as Netflix) and/or (b) created an icon set in a transparent background so the image appears to be three dimensional and again, not set in the default shiny button

I have looked through the build settings, but cannot see how to configure.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include the below key into your info.plist file.

"icon already includes gloss effects" and make check checkbox as marked.

So, your app icon will be as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following steps.

- Open your app's `Info.plist` file.
- Add a new row.
- Select the key - `Icon already includes gloss effects`.
- Set `YES` as the value for that key.