# iPhone icon without semi circle

Tags: ios, ios4, icons

I have an iPhone icon that shows up on the home screen.  The icon is looking bad because of the semi circle overlay being added.  How can I get rid of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon)

Answer (score 4):

just set this Key in your info.plist:

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
```

`UIPrerenderedIcon` to `YES`

if you are using newer versions use this:

`Icon already includes gloss and bevel effects` to `YES` (Just TICK it)

Hope it helps, if you need help comment!

---

This have been asked many times before, you may want to search here for a more detailed answer..
Here is a good one: [How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon/1004315#1004315)

Comment: Where do I tick that setting?

Comment: I dont see a key called "Information Property List" in "Edit Project Settings"

Comment: You should look in the left panel where your files and classes are and expand all your folders, you should have a file "info.plist". There you add a key and look for the item in the answer depending on your SDK version

Answer (score 2):

In IOS 5 it's now called, "Icon already includes gloss effects" then set it to "YES"