# Removing the gloss from app icon when app installed on the device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiapplication

When we pass the Application icon files inside CFBundleIconFiles, we get a rounded gloss on upper half of the icon. How can we get rid of it like in icon for "Settings" app.

Comment: I am pretty sure this question has been asked to death here.

Comment: For example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon

Comment: Sometimes you just want to try google.
http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=iphone+app+icon+no+gloss
Amongst the results:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `UIPrerenderedIcon` to `YES` in your `Info.plist` file.