# how to remove glare effect from icon from p-list?

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon)

I want to remove glare effect from my app icon and someone told me it could be done from plist file but he doesn't know from where it can be done? so plz tell me how to remove glare effect from app icon using plist?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are articles around here that already say where.

Comment: You should look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define property `Icon already includes gloss effects` and set its value to `YES` in your `Info.plist` file in project.

Or add lines to the same plist file (if you are editing in `Source Code` mode):

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
```