# IOS4 removing shadow of the icon of the application

Tags: icons, ios4

I have given an icon to my application the image i am giving is not having any shadow over it but on iphone it shows the shadow over the icon.
Is it possible to remove the shadow.

Comment: I think your problem is already solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,you can Remove shadow by doing this.

Include a row in the info.plist file of your app `Icon already includes gloss effects` and checkmark the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

To remove shadow of the icon of the application, Just do this:

[image]