# Invalid image path ios7 icons when Deploying to appstore via Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

I'm receiving an error whenever I attempt to send my application in for review, it appears to be stating the ios7 icons for my app have invalid paths but the icons work in the simulator and on a dev device. It's also stating that it's unable to authenticate the package.

I've attempted to update the paths in the info.plist file but the issue persists.

```
Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/x3/4cy637515hs8ct3096ssqg_r0000gn/T/725271208.itmsp - Error Messages:
        Apple's web service operation was not successful
        Unable to authenticate the package: 725271208.itmsp
        ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'Icon@152'" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
        ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'Icon@76'" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
        ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'Icon@120'" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

Comment: I'm having this problem during "Validation". The app and icons work correctly on device for dev and AdHoc (TestFlight). Icons are specified same as for other apps successfully submitted to the App Store. This is my first attempt to submit with Xcode 5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select Use Asset Catalog (I opted for just doing it for the App Icons and not the Launch Images because my No image found errors were all related to App Icons, as yours seem to be), then drag and drop the appropriate icons into their correct spots.

The first time I did this it was a bit messed up, I believe because I had set the resources, so I ended up selecting "Don't use asset catalogs" which reset the resources to be blank, deleted the asset catalog, and then selected Use Asset Catalog again.

At this point all the spots were blank and I was able to drag and drop the correct assets to the correct places.  Note that there is no 1x 60pt iOS 7 icon slot.

I found this other related thread which had the answer:
[How do you update the app icons and launch images to support IOS 6 and 7 simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624587/how-do-you-update-the-app-icons-and-launch-images-to-support-ios-6-and-7-simulta)

Comment: That did the trick, I had tried using a asset catalog before but only migrated to it instead of starting out fresh.

Comment: Migrating worked for me. It seems that XCode 5.0 (5A1413) is just broken in this respect. Legacy issues!

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution to this problem is to delete references to image assets in your plist if you are using the asset catalog, or fix the paths if you're not.

Comment: Indeed indeed ... strange those entries are not auto-cleaned up when asset catalogs are used, this is easy to overlook. Especially because it only is detected when submitting to the App Store.

Comment: This worked.  Delete the images, then add them again--something you'd think CLEAN would do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved this Issue , Just Remove  references to all the icons , and  open the PLIST and also Delete the icons from there , add the icons again in your Project , to fix these problem