# App icon not showing up on iPhone 5 device during testing

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

I have a 120x120 icon image that's working fine on emulators - however when I try it on my device, the icon doesn't show up. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a similar issue, an app don't show the icon immediately, but if I restart the device, the icon appear, isn't a solution, but this happen to me.

Comment: gave this a try, didn't work :(

Comment: Are you using the new asset catalog?

Comment: yes - i just dragged the icons into the Images.xcassets holders.

Comment: and you've verified that everything looks good when you go project->select your target -> general -> view the image assets?

Comment: yes - everything looks fine.

Comment: Delete the app off of your device and then reinstall it.

Comment: I tried that also - no luck

Comment: does the fact that the 120x120 icon corners are 90 degrees?

Comment: Delete those image references from App Icon section.And put them back again..

Comment: Please check your answer at [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624587/how-do-you-update-the-app-icons-and-launch-images-to-support-ios-6-and-7-simulta

Comment: @Nirmit I saw that already but that didn't help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out. This was actually really annoying. So the UI designer had simply renamed his .psd files with .png and xcode thought this was fine. However, renaming the .pngs isn't going to automatically make them real .pngs. The way I solved this was going to mac preview and exporting the files to the PNG format.

Comment: Super annoying. How is this person a designer?

Comment: This was my my exact issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes some of the images get cached by the OS.

- Delete your app completely from your mobile device (press and hold, then delete the app)
- Turn off your device and turn it on again.(This ensures that the cache gets cleared)
- In xCode, clean the project and rebuild.
- Load the software again you your device.

You should be able to see your icon as long as its properly added to your project.

Comment: What's the project file?

Comment: sorry thats unclear, I meant if you can provide the entire (or stripped down version) of the project source

Comment: Hrm - there's no real project source if I'm using xcassets? if there is where would you like to look?

Answer (score 3):

Drag your app over another app to group both into a folder. Then drag the app out of the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Check your info.plist file. Make sure the icon entry looks something like this (use your own image file names of course):

[image]

If you see another "Icon already includes gloss effects" row outside, remove it.

Comment: I dont' have one of these. I'm using xcassets from storyboards

Comment: If you're using the xcassets, try going to Target > General > App Icons and select the correct source.

Answer (score 2):

It is not uncommon not to see your app icon on the device. However, when your app is being uploaded to the App Store, everything will be fine.

Is your iOS device running iOS7? If not, you will need to include 57x57 and 114x114 icons as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737063/1646862 for icon sizes apple requires. It is always good to include all icon sizes you may need in your iOS bundle.

Comment: I'm running iOS7 so it should show up. Would I be ok submitting to the Apple store then?