# App Icon doesn't show up on iPod(No issue in iPhone or iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Tried:
Added all the icons of required sizes in Assets -> Appicon

Xcode version : 9.2
iPod version : 9.3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App icon not showing up on iPhone 5 device during testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433144/app-icon-not-showing-up-on-iphone-5-device-during-testing)

Comment: Thanks vandit,I had my app's icon image in jpg format so exporting it to png format solved the issue.