# iOS different App icon for iOS 6 and iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, xcode4.5

In my single binary which is to upload to App Store, I want to give two different app icons, one is for iOS 6 and one is for iOS 7 (which will be shown on home screen of device). As when I set iOS 7 designed icon, it looks odd in iOS 6.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store App settings, belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am fairly certain this question is on-topic. It's a question for developers, and apple.stackexchange.com is for "power **users** of Apple hardware and software.".

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I have to agree with `Jonathan` here it is on topic but I would say it isn't very clear from the title. As it seems like they wanted different icons in the App Store itself where as the question asked indicates different App Icons when downloaded. `CocoaNoob` please could you make it more clear by updating your title or question. If you do mean App Store icons and not App Icons then I am with `Shivan Raptor` that would be off-topic

Comment: corrected, thank you for notifying it @Popeye

Comment: May be this is one is rellevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18624587/365188

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 5, delete the default `Images.xcassets` asset catalog and add a new one with the same name. You need to do this because the default asset catalog is missing some of the icon presets.

The default assets catalog has these presets:

[image]

Recreating the assets catalog gives you these presets:

[image]

Comment: nope.. The new one is empty.. now what??

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the icons for iOS6 and iOS7, just need to give appstore icon...
http://makeappicon.com/