# App Icon not shown on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing iPhone app. When i run the app on **iPhone** i can see the the icon on Home screen. But when i run the same app on **iPad** whitish icon appears which normally appears when the app has no icon.

I have tested my other **iPhone** apps they are working fine but this is causing trouble. I used **Asset Catalogs** to display app icons and they are perfectly adjusting in it. What could be the problem here any suggestions?

Comment: If you added the iPad icons after the first install, you may uninstall it from the iPad and install it again.

Comment: I can only see three icons 120*120, 80*80, 58*58 not asking for iPad separate. i tried uninstalling cleaning app but still no use.

Comment: Must we manually prepare icons of all sizes, and match the required sizes precisely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

xCode 5 was not showing anything related to iPad for an iPhone only app. So when i migrated my images to **Assets Catalogs** and clicked on app icon in the **Attribute Inspector** i was given the options like i want to give icons for iPad. So i provided and problem solved :)

Comment: to extend the accepted answer, make sure the app icons are not manufactured as png. Even if you convert the jpg to png and run it in device, then it won't work in the device even if it does in simulator. That was my terrible experience.

Comment: png is fine, and here are some more characters.

Answer (score 16):

I also initially started with developing the app for iPhone and then needed to add iPad icons and here where I found them:

1) go to Assets
2) find appIcon (usually on top)
3) go to attributes inspector
4) choose iPad ios swift version
5) iPad iCons holders will appear you will need to fill them

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had added icons, then i went and made my app universal, but when i went back to AppIcons it was not showing the iTablet stuff. This was the issue, in attributes section i had to select iPad.

Answer (score 0):

In project settings there are fields for both, iPad and iPhone icons. You may want to provide different icons for different devices, so try providing your icon for both, iPad and iPhone. Even though it will be the same image.

Comment: I can only see three icons 120*120, 80*80, 58*58 not asking for iPad separate. i tried uninstalling cleaning app but still no use.

Comment: Did you try cleaning build folder? Hold ALT and perform project clean. In my case, i can modify icons for both, iphone and ipad (using xCode 5)

Comment: I am also using xCode5. I tried using  cleaning using alt + simple clean. If your app is iphone only it will not display iPad resolution icons

Comment: Do you have "Images.xcassets" folder in your project? If so - click it and look if there are more icon options to choose.

Answer (score 0):

for Universal application iPad Icon file size is 72x72 and named Icon-72 and for Retina its 114x114 with Icon-72@2x.png. Try to include this files into your resource bundle and then build your app

Answer (score 0):

In project settings there are fields for App Icons please refer to the attachment[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. go to general  , then app icon source , then click the appicon
2. by default , you can't see the place for ipad

3 . left click and create a new image set

4. then you can see all icon size , add the  @76 @152 for ipad

Answer (score 0):

In my case i do have set images for iPad in my assets but even then it was not showing. I have to **check Target Membership** check box. I had imported AppIcons folder and this got uncheck. [image: Target Selection]

Answer (score -1):

Hope the stackoverflow link will help [How do you update the app icons and launch images to support IOS 6 and 7 simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624587/how-do-you-update-the-app-icons-and-launch-images-to-support-ios-6-and-7-simulta)

As answered by Andy Bean, try using Asset Catalog.

Link 2: [iOS 7 App Icons, Launch images And Naming Convention While Keeping iOS 6 Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons)