# Is it possible to prevent the iPhone from adding the 'shine' to my app's icon?

Tags: iphone, icons

When you define an icon for your app in XCode and then run it in the simulator or on a real device, the icon is automatically trimmed so it has rounded edges and a 'glossy' sheen is applied over top of the icon.  I'd like to get rid of that sheen since it's obscuring some of the detail in my icon.  It seems like some other apps are able to accomplish this... anyone know how it's done?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon

Comment: And Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236376/how-do-you-override-the-icon-for-iphone-apps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this key/value pair to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Is this still true for the current version of Xcode? And if so, where exactly in the Info.plist is this added? TIA

Comment: Yes, it is still true. In Xcode 4, however, the key appears as "Icon already includes gloss effects".

Comment: In iOS5 devices it's no longer a root key, you need a CFBundleIcons dictionary with a CFBundlePrimaryIcon dictionary entry in it, which contains the UIPrerenderedIcon key along with an array of CFBundleIconFiles.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.3 it's even easier...just go to your Target settings -> summary and next to your app icons check "Prerendered" - it removes that sheen