# Taking the highlight off of Icons

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

When programming and looking at all different apps I have realized that some apps in the app store don't have the lit highlight on the top, making it look more 3D. I have an app idea but I need to take the highlight off. The app have been programmed in Xcode, so if anyone answers, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145887/is-it-possible-to-prevent-the-iphone-from-adding-the-shine-to-my-apps-icon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html :

> If you choose, you can prevent iPhone
>   OS from adding the shine to your icon.
>   To do this, you need to add the
>   UIPrerenderedIcon key to your
>   application’s Info.plist file (read
>   “The Information Property List” in
>   iPhone Application Programming Guide
>   to learn about this file). Your icon
>   should still measure 57 x 57 pixels,
>   regardless of whether you take
>   advantage of the added shine.

Comment: Now you can just check the _Prerendered_ box in the App Icon section of the Summary page.