# How do I create an iPhone application icon without the standard reflective look?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons

Xcode automatically resizes and applies a glossy look to images added as the application icon. However, I've seen some apps without the glossy finish. How do I disable the glossy icon look?
Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236376/how-do-you-override-the-icon-for-iphone-apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `UIPrerenderedIcon` (type = `Boolean`, value = `true` or checked) to your application .plist file.

Comment: Thanks! Here is the code for anyone who needs it. 

 <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
 <true/>

Answer (score 1):

now it should be "Icon already includes gloss effects" (Value = YES) row in your application .plist file